# Wordpress: Freight as a product

Tags: e-commerce, wordpress

I'm working for a freight company and now we are going to offer customers to pay for freight in advance online. We are using Wordpress e-commerce plugin

I'm a developer and I'm looking for the best way I could put this together. As I think now, I have two options:

1. Make a regular WPEC product extended by custom fields: taking measurements from the customer (width, height, length and weight) and calculate the price from an algorithm. I could use Product Variations for fixed priced goods (tires, bicycle, guitar etc.). And then some checkboxes for "Express delivery" or "Insurance" etc. How would I take these values in checkout to do the actual calculation? (and at the same time as the customer is giving the values before check out for that matter?)
2. Make a Custom plugin? Would it be easier and more clean to do a custom plugin? (Instead of tweaking others)?

PS. I'm looking for a way which benefits the customer more than the developer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon the most flexible approach is [writing a custom shipping module](http://getshopped.org/resources/docs/get-involved/writing-a-new-shipping-module/). You can then create basic products with variations that take in your metrics, allowing you to pre-configure certain product types like bicycles, tyres, guitars, but also generic stuff that has weight, length/width/height, etc. You can add shipping modes of standard vs express, and a checkbox for insurance, as options on the shipping module.

Start off by looking at the bundled shipping modules under `wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/wpsc-shipping/`